only view pdf annotation in react native app
Is There is any open sourced react native package which can display the annotate pdf.
pdf is annotated in web using pdf-annotate.js annotated data is received through api in app there is only requirement to display annotated pdf.

in web pdf.js works but in react native  can it work as it is web based library.

react-native-pdf:
This library allows you to display PDFs in your React Native app.
It supports both local and remote PDF files.
However, it does not natively support annotations created with pdf-annotate.js.
react-native-pdf-lib:
This library allows creating and modifying PDF documents.
You can use this library to render annotations, but it requires manual handling of the annotations data.
pdf-lib:
This is a JavaScript library that can be used to create and modify PDF documents.
You can use it in conjunction with react-native-pdf to render annotations on your PDF
